# No Model Stored with Mlr3

Tags: mlr3

I am performing nested resampling using the following code:

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE))

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer)
```

At the end of the run, I get the following message:

```
Error: No model stored`
```

If I specify store_models=TRUE, the run crashes for this large model due to RAM consumption. I am currently running the models on RStudio Workbench with 128GB of RAM. Therefore, I read that not specifying a store_model argument would not store the intermediate models to reduce RAM consumption but that I would be able to extract predictions and some performance measures to report. However, this is when I ran into the error. I haven't tried setting the store_backends=FALSE. Would this potentially help in any way?

Any assistance/insight into where I may be going wrong and how to adjust parameters to get this nested resampling to run and be able to extract predictions/performance measures would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: We will change the aggregation of the importance values in the next mlr3fselect version. This version should be on GitHub in a day or two. I can let you know here in the comments.

Comment: New version on GH. Will be version 0.10.0 on CRAN.

Comment: Thanks! When I used remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3fselect@model") it failed so I downloaded the version on GH using remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3fselect@main"). The version loaded shows 0.9.1.9000 but I'm not sure it is working. The RAM seems to be precipitously increasing over the run and will likely max out like it did previously. I set store_models = TRUE in benchmark() and set store_models = FALSE in AutoFSelector. I assume I must be making a small mistake somewhere?

Comment: As an update, I let it keep running and it is doing so rather than crashing. However, I do receive the following message (Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  cannot popen '/bin/which 'pdflatex' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'). It takes a while to run so not sure of what the output will look like or whether it will end up crashing later.

Comment: Yes, you did that right. The model branch is merged to main. Maybe you should try out how much RAM is needed to fit one model. To me it looks more like you are having trouble getting one model into RAM than storing the models of the nested resampling.

Comment: Thanks! Just posted (as an answer) details (and code) of the things I've tried to try and narrow down where I may be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new version. Install the development version with `remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3fselect@model")`. The models are now saved until the importance is extracted. So if you use holdout resampling you need enough RAM for one model.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try. Just to clarify, with the new version, where should I specify store_models as TRUE in the nested resample call? In just the AutoFSelector$new, resample, or both?

Comment: You're welcome. You set `store_models = TRUE` in `resample()` and set `store_models = FALSE` in `AutoFSelector`.

Comment: Great! I'll try it out. Two follow-up questions: 1) Will this paradigm also work with 1) benchmark instead of resample and 2) auto_tuner being used as the "at" portion of a nested resampling call instead of AutoFSelector? I am also running a glmnet elastic net model that I'd like to be able to extract the features and tuning parameters from the inner loop in a memory-efficient manner, if possible?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No. You could write a callback for this. The callback extracts the features from the models, writes them to the archive and discards the models. The [early stopping callback](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3tuning/blob/main/R/mlr_callbacks.R) is similar. It extracts the optimal number of boosting rounds from XGBoost models. You could modify this callback.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following code it uses about 30GB RAM (I have 128GB on my RStudio Pro System):

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

lgr::get_logger("mlr3")$set_threshold("info")
lgr::get_logger("bbotk")$set_threshold("info")

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type="prob", importance = "permutation", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

resampling = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

instance = FSelectInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task,
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  store_models = TRUE)

fselector = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE)

fselector$optimize(instance)
```

When I would run the following code as part of nested resampling prior to the package update it would max out RAM and crash:

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type="prob", importance = "permutation", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models=TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer, store_models=TRUE)
```

Also, when I would run the following code as part of nested resampling prior to the package update it would max out RAM and crash:

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type="prob", importance = "permutation", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models=FALSE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer, store_models=TRUE)
```

When I would run the following code as part of nested resampling prior to the package update it would also use about 30GB of RAM but wouldn't have any of the inner FSelect results:

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type="prob", importance = "permutation", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models=TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer)
```

Then if I run the following code with the GitHub version of the package, the RAM maxes out and crashes:

```r
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type="prob", importance = "permutation", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models=FALSE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer, store_models=TRUE)
```

That is why I was thinking the nested resampling was the cause of the issue. Any thoughts on any calls I should tweak? Maybe store_backends?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Do you parallelize with `future`? Can you check the size of `learner$model`?

Comment: I haven't been parallelizing with future. I've just allocated multiple threads to the learner. I just checked the the size of learner$model using the object size function for the code that uses 30GB of RAM and runs (first one) and it was only 28666304 bytes.

Comment: Okay we should move the discussion to [GH](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3fselect/issues/77).

Comment: Can you please run the code from GH on your RStudio Workbench and write your results on GH.