# extract_inner_fselect_results is NULL with mlr3 Nested Resampling

Tags: rstudio-server, mlr3

This question is an extension of the following question: [No Model Stored with Mlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75405217/no-model-stored-with-mlr3).

I have been performing nested resampling to get an unbiased metric of model performance. If I don't specify store_models=TRUE then I get **Error: No model stored** at the end of the run. However, if I specify store_models=TRUE in both the at and resample calls then RStudio crashes due to RAM consumption.

I have now tried the following code in which I specified store_models=TRUE for just the at call:

```
MSvCon<-read.csv("MS v Control Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

MSvCon$Status<-as.factor(MSvCon$Status)

MSvCon[,2:4399]<-scale(MSvCon[,2:4399], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_classif(MSvCon, target = "Status")

learner = lrn("classif.ranger", importance = "impurity", num.trees=10000)

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

measure = msr("classif.fbeta", beta=1, average="micro")

terminator = trm("none")

resampling_inner = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models=TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer)
```

After finishing, I am able to extract performance measures successfully. However, I tried to use extract_inner_fselect_results and extract_inner_fselect_archives to check what features were selected and importance measures but received a NULL result.

Do you have any suggestions on what I would need to adjust in my code to see this information? I anticipate that adding store_models=TRUE to the resample call would but the RAM consumption issue (even using 128GB on Rstudio Workbench) prevents that. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The archives of the inner resampling are stored in the model slot of the `AutoFSelector`s i.e. without `store_models = TRUE` in `resample()` you cannot access the inner results and archives. I will write a workaround for you and answer in the other question.